# Alamofire: file download and validation failure

Tags: ios, swift, validation, download, alamofire

In my iOS project I'm using `Alamofire` library to download remote documents (from a server with Basic Auth) in this way:

```
let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("foo.pdf")
    return (filePath.url, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
}

Alamofire.download(myUrlRequest, to: destination).authenticate(user: user, password: password, persistence: .none).validate().response { response in
    print(response)
    if response.error == nil, let path = response.destinationURL?.path {
        print(path)
    }
}
```

This works great! The file is correctly downloaded in the app's Documents folder.

My problem is when `user` or/and `password` are wrong. In this case server response status is `401 Unauthorized` and `.validate()` method correctly fails, but in my Documents folder I find the file "foo.pdf" where the content is a xml that explains the `401` error. What I would like is the file saved only if the validate doesn't fail.

My questions: is there a way, with Alamofire, to save the file just in case the response is validated? Or do I have to manually delete the file when validate fails?

Comment: it's 3 years since, but did you found any simple solution?

Answer (score 2):

I am having the similar issue at the moment. So far, the only thing I could think of is crude

```
if response.error != nil {
    try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: destinationURL)
}
```

in response closure.

I will investigate further though.

EDIT 1:

It seems this issue quite some time ago brought this behaviour https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/233

Comment: what if we don't want to remove the previous good file automatically? xD